# PHP OOP MVC Fatal Error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, scope

So I've been looking all around, but nothing seems to be relevant to my problem.

I have an MVC, with some controllers and some tools like Session handling.

The session class consists of non-static methods, and in my controller I'm instantiating the session class like this:

```
public $sessions;
public function __construct () {
     $this->sessions = new Session();
}
```

However, when I call it from a method in the controller, it returns the infamous "Using $this when not in object context". It doesn't make any sense to me.

```
public function index() {
     $this->sessions->get('sessionToGet');
}
```

This will return the error.

Comment: Post complete class code (save for irrelevant methods), this code looks correct.

Comment: One thing I can think of is that your constructor is not being called. Maybe because your controller class is a base class. Kindly try to include parent::__construct();// Kindly verify the syntax

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think it's a fault of how I wrote it. I came up with a better solution, which enabled me to switch to static calls instead on the session wrapper.

Fixed my problem, and now it atleast works very well.